# jQuery - display of calculations based on form update with keyup

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-calculation

It is a basic sample order form with 4 input (units number). When I put values in, all corresponding information being displayed and calulations made (unit * price). Each time I add another item I want to get total value of order. There is something wrong with orderTotal calculation when values are being updated and when I clear value at all  Order Total dissapear completly. Im very new to jQuery and will need some help with with, please.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/97tnrepg/4/

and the code:

```js
var orderTotal = 0 ;
$(".pack").keyup(function () {
    var curId = this.id.split("k")[1];
    var packName = $('#pack' + curId + '-name').val();
    var packPrice = $('#pack' + curId + '-price').val();
    var packUnit = $(this).val();
    var packTotal = packUnit * packPrice;
    
    orderTotal = orderTotal + packTotal;
    
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
         $("#packcontent_" + curId).hide();
         $("#order_total").hide();  
    } else {
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).html('Units : ' + packUnit + ', Name :  ' + packName + ', Price : ' + packPrice + ', Total : ' + packTotal);
        $("#packcontent_" + curId).show();
      $("#order_total").html('Order Total: ' +orderTotal);
      $("#order_total").show();   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_01" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_02" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_03" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="content" id="packcontent_04" style="display: none;"></div>

<div class="content" id="order_total" style="display: none;"></div>

<p>Pack 1</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack01" id="pack01" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" value="" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack01-name" name="pack01-name" value="Pack 1" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack01-price" name="pack01-price" value="5.00" />
<p>Pack 2</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack02" value="" id="pack02" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack02-name" name="pack02-name" value="Pack 2" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack02-price" name="pack02-price" value="6.00" />
<p>Pack 3</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack03" value="" id="pack03" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack03-name" name="pack03-name" value="Pack 3" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack03-price" name="pack03-price" value="7.00" />
<p>Pack 4</p>
<input type="text" class="pack" name="pack04" value="" id="pack04" autocomplete="off" maxlength="2" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack04-name" name="pack04-name" value="Pack 4" />
<input type="hidden" class="pack" id="pack04-price" name="pack04-price" value="8.00" />
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ok, i see that $("#order_total").hide();   is in the wrong place from the logic point of view. It should only be activated if all the inputs are empty. How i can code that ??

Comment: can you try this fiddle @Nita? http://jsfiddle.net/97tnrepg/8/ let me know if this works for you.

Comment: did it work for you @Nita?

Comment: Thanks. There is part of the code that i already learn from. But still once you change the values orderTotal keep growing and if you clear imputs or just simply 0 them it doesn't seem to affact orderTotal at all and for the reason that is always bigger then 0 will always be visible, even if there is none in "check out form". i Hope i expleaind my self properly.

Comment: Try to update inputs to see whats happening.

Comment: the reason is if you blank your row or simply set it to 0, you're just hiding that div but the value is still there

Comment: working on a better solution. give me a few minutes

Comment: here you go @Nita. http://jsfiddle.net/97tnrepg/13/ try this and let me know if it has any issues

Comment: if i understand the question correctly, the total was not working and if u edit an existing value, it was calculating it wrongly correct?

Comment: Sorry took my some time to analyze and test the code, it is working better, but if for example you do input some values in all fields and update them it works fine, but once you start 0 them or make the inputs empty, there is always last value left in total. Fill them all in and then empty them all to see what i mean.

Comment: oh darn.. the reason it has the last value is because i update the div only if the value is greater than 0

Comment: this one should work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/97tnrepg/16/

Comment: Big thank you @Sushil. I only added if(total == 0){  $("#order_total").hide();    } at the end so if value of total is 0 nothing is being shown! Perfect

Comment: wah.. great. so finally you're happy with the solution. let me post this as an answer. please accept it if it helped you :)

Comment: i've posted my solution @Nita. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Also if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == '0' ) to avoid displaying items with value set to 0

Comment: yeah. thats how it should be. Can you please accept my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're storing and updating your total in each iteration, you can try creating an orders array that will hold a list of orders. so this would be dynamic incase you add more orders in the future.

what you can do is create an orders array like this.

```
var orders = [];
```

then create 3 function for getting, updating and calculating the total of the orders

Getting an Order

```
function GetOrder(curId){
    var order = null;

    for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
        if(orders[i].id == curId){
            order = orders[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return order;
}
```

updating an Order

```
function UpdateOrders(order){
    for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
        if(orders[i].id == order.id){
            orders[i] = order;
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

calculating the Total

```
function CalculateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i< orders.length; i++){
        total = total + orders[i].packTotal;
    }
    console.log(total);
    $("#order_total").html('Order Total: ' + total);
    if(total > 0){

        $("#order_total").show();
    }
}
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97tnrepg/16/)** for the same. hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nita. let me know if you have any other issues with jquery and javascript.